# get targeted runtime server in eclipse: plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am doing plugin development. I want to get the users target runtime server. In example, if they are running Tomcat 6, or Tomcat 7, I want to know which server they are using. Is this possible? I am using IProject, IWorkspace, etc. Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IFacetedProject class to get the targeted runtime servers...

```
IFacetedProject fp = ProjectFacetsManager.create(model.getProject(), true, null);
Set<IRuntime> runtimeSet = fp.getTargetedRuntimes();
```

So this will return a set of all the targeted runtimes that the user has selected.
For instance, Tomcat 7, Tomcat 6, etc will be returned.

Comment: Very nice, didn't know about this api

Answer (score 1):

`ServletContext` has the method `getServerInfo()`

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServerInfo%28%29

Another approach is looking at the System.properties at runtime, for example  JBoss 4 defines the `jboss.server.dir` system property.